# How do I ask my previous managing director for a recommendation she offered when I was leaving?

Tags: united-kingdom, recommendation-letter, previous-employer

I recently left my job where I had been working for around 8 months. When I was leaving, I had a short meeting with the managing director where she offered to give me a letter of recommendation.

It has been around 2 months since I left, and I really need to get the recommendation from her but I'm not sure how to ask. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can write an email requesting a letter of recommendation?

Answer (score 88):

You're overthinking this.

> Hi $MD_NAME.
>
> When I left $COMPANY_NAME 2 months ago, you kindly offered to give me a letter of recommendation. While I didn't need this at the time, it would be very helpful if you could write that for me now.
>
> Hope everything is still going well at $COMPANY_NAME.
>
> Thanks,
>
> Tango

Answer (score -5):

"Hey *previous MD* - Sorry to bug you, I've been a little bit busy with all the recent changes - I know we talked about a letter of Recommendation - I've checked my emails and my files and I can't seem to find it - did you send it through? If so, can you resend it, or if not - can you send it through now? I'd really appreciate it.

Hope everything is going well on your end"

Simple, polite, puts the fault on yourself (people are more obliged if they don't feel they are being blamed) and it's conversational.

Comment: Respectfully, do you often craft your writing as long sentences broken up by multiple dashes? Makes it very jerky to read, at least for me.

Comment: @InBedded16 - all good, often I do. It depends on the context and the style - for more informal communication (like this) or an off-hand email to someone you are on good terms with, it's how I'd do it.

Comment: Personally I try to avoid "sorry". Maybe they like the mail, and now the tone is already set. That is super generic advise, sometimes you should use sorry, but I try to set the tone positive and "sorry" doesnt do that :)

Comment: @Martijn that depends on location. question is tagged UK, so "sorry" is commonly used

Comment: While I do generally agree that people appreciate when others take the blame/responsibility and leave them off the hook, this specific example struck me instead as leaning towards "passive aggressive" and it actually seems to imply that an agreement to write the letter was struck and the MD failed to follow-up, when it's just as possible that MD made an *offer* to write the letter that OP did not fully and enthusiastically accept/request. I think it would be better for OP to assume their fault was in failure to properly request the letter than the suggestion that it's been lost.

Comment: This wording would give me the impression that you think the other side owes you to write the letter. You imply you were too busy to check mails or read the letter if had been send, so it sounds like some status report you requested from a subordinate who didn't do their job and that they should "send it through now". I would probably write the complete opposite: Acknowledge that the MD is probably busy but that you would appreciate if they find the time to write you the letter. No bullshit "It's my fault for not finding the mail you didn't send".

Comment: I don't agree with the formatting (the dashes are - annoying and - not punctuation), but I agree on principle. It could be tweaked by the OP (as I'd hope all advice gained at any SE site is) to fit the precise situation to maybe state "I probably wasn't clear enough at our meeting, but I'd really like that recommendation you offered", if that's the appropriate phrasing.